# Validations with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm attempting to use the simple_form gem in order to create forms.  I'm also using twitter bootstrap for styling, so there are certain cases where simple_form is too rigid to do what I want to do (not always).

I'm submitting a form that should fail on validation, which it does.  However, when it renders the page again, it doesn't display error messages near the input, and the page only half renders.

**Controller Code**: (note, I'm essentially using show/edit action as the same thing)

```
def update
  @contact = current_resource
  authorize! :update, @contact

  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.update_attributes(params[:customer_relationship_contact])
      format.html { redirect_to customer_relationship_contact_url(@contact), notice: "#{@contact.to_s} was successfully updated." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def show
  @contact = current_resource
  authorize! :show, @contact

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @contact }
  end
end
```

**View/Form Code**:

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:novalidate => true} do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<fieldset>

  <legend>Contract</legend>
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="controls controls-row">
        <%= f.label :tax_id_number, 'Social Security No.' %>
        <%= f.text_field :tax_id_number, class: 'span12', placeholder: 'Social Security No.' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", customer_relationship_contacts_path, :class => 'btn' %>
</div>
```

**Model Validation**:

```
    validates :tax_id_number, format: { with: /\A[0-9]+\z/, message: "Please enter only numbers without dashes." }, allow_blank: true
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`twitter_bootstrap_form_for`](https://github.com/stouset/twitter_bootstrap_form_for) gem? there is also a branch for [bootstrap 2.0](https://github.com/stouset/twitter_bootstrap_form_for/tree/bootstrap-2.0).

Comment: It appears that gem doesn't support inline error messages, which is really what I'm going after here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using `f.label` and `f.text_field` in your view - simple form is built to be simple, so what you need is `f.input` - so in this case:

```
<%= f.input :tax_id_number, label: 'Social Security No.', placeholder: 'Social Security No.' %>
```

Here is what happens - `f.input` will create a surround div with an input class.  Within that div is the label and the input. If there are any errors, simple form will add the class `field_with_errors` to the surrounding div and add a span containing the message after the input with the class `error`.  This will not happen if you don't use `f.input`

All that is left is to style them with css.